# How to make obsolete Hangul display correctly?

Tags: hangul

When looking up etymologies of Korean words that apparently involve hangul characters that are no longer in use (for example 따뜻하다 < 다 , 다) I usually only get to see those boxes with their Unicode codes inside. Where can I find a font that displays these characters correctly?

Comment: You may also use [CyberChef](http://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=From_Charcode('Space',10)&input=NDQwMCA0NDg5IDQ1MjM) and change the numbers in the input.

Answer (score 4):

Here is [Korean Wikipedia article about old hangul](https://ko.wikipedia.org/wiki/%EC%98%9B%ED%95%9C%EA%B8%80), and [Namu Wiki article about old hangul](https://namu.wiki/w/%EC%98%9B%ED%95%9C%EA%B8%80) and here is list of fonts.

> Wikipedia
>
> > ...은글꼴이나 함초롬체, 본고딕 또는 본명조...
> >
> > 맑은고딕
>
> Namu wiki
>
> > 나눔바른고딕 옛한글
> >
> > 나눔명조 옛한글
> >
> > 본고딕
> >
> > 맑은고딕 after windows 8
> >
> > 은글꼴 partitially
> >
> > 함초롬바탕, 함초롬돋움
> >
> > 새굴림
> >
> > 한컴바탕, 한컴돋움, 새바탕
> >
> > 전주완판본체

So here is link to font above.

- [은글꼴(UnFont)](http://kldp.net/unfonts/)
- [함초롬체(Hamchorom Font)](https://www.hancom.com/cs_center/csDownload.do?div=15&ver=139)
- [본고딕(Source Han Sans/Noto Sans CJK)](https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-han-sans/tree/release)
- [본명조(Source Han Serif/Noto Serif CJK)](https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-han-serif/tree/release)
- Malgun gothic is default multilingual font of windows.
- [나눔바른고딕 옛한글](https://hangeul.naver.com/2014/archaicword) : press `나눔옛한글 설치하기` -> `윈도우용`(for windows) or `맥용`(for mac). Above is TTF, below is OTF. Press `설치`(install) at the program to install. Make sure to unselect checkbox at the last page, or it will install naver toolbar and make starting webpage to naver.
- Can't find download page for 새굴림/한컴바탕/한컴돋움.
- [전주완판본체](http://www.jeonju.go.kr/index.9is?contentUid=9be517a75cfc1850015d0becebbf4672) : Press `전주완판본체 다운로드`.

`다`(ㅼ + ㆍ + ㅅ two times and ㅎ + ㆍ) and `다`(ㄷ + ㆍ +ㅅ and ㅎ + ㆍ) looks perfectly at `나눔바른고딕 옛한글`, `새굴림`, and `함초롬바탕`, somewhat ugly in `함초롬돋움`. And not in `맑은고딕`.